# Where is Jawenko Lava Beast?

Tags: super-star-wars

I've been a huge fan of the Super Star Wars trilogy eversince.

Especially the first installment of this season seems to have some annoying bosses.
Jawenko Lava Beast is one of them. Actually he can be a bit of a pain to get past.

So I was watching this [speedrun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_yXQuNPov8) the other day, and as soon as Luke advances to the ground level of the Sandcrawler I get curious what happens..

Well what happens is that Jawenko just doesn't show up. Also R2-D2 seems to join him having a break.

On my cartridge I have to face Jawenko in Easy and Brave mode. Don't know about the highest difficulty yet.

So where the heck are the two of them?

Comment: So to clarify, are you asking why they did not appear in the speedrun linked in the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost three years after I asked this question I did some more research and found the explanation:

> Probably the biggest skip you can do in the entire game, he can Only spawn if you have the Lava on the screen, to avoid this you can use the Camera angle glitch during the mini boss and forward and he won't spawn, just make sure to not fall all the way down in the shaft so the lava spawns. I highly recommend this for JEDI no death run.

Source:
http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/super-star-wars/282901-super-star-wars-glitch-general-secrets-guide.html